# HTML to Markdown JavaScript converter

Tags: gratis, open-source, javascript, html, markdown

Searching a JavaScript library that should convert HTML code to Markdown format.

It should have the following features:

- convert basic HTML tags to Markdown (`h1...6`, `pre`, `code` etc)
- keep the HTML code if it hasn't a correspondent in Markdown (e.g. `iframe`)
- work on server side (NodeJS)
- work on client side (browser)

First three points are important for me, but any recs/suggestions are welcome.

---

## Examples

```
HTML                                    | Converted
----------------------------------------+---------------------------------
<h1>Hello World</h1>                    | # Hello World
----------------------------------------+---------------------------------
<h1 class="foo">Hello World</h1>        | <h1 class="foo">Hello World</h1>
----------------------------------------+---------------------------------
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>                      | Lorem ipsum
----------------------------------------+---------------------------------
<p data-something="foo">Lorem ipsum</p> | <p data-something="foo">Lorem ipsum</p>
----------------------------------------+---------------------------------
<img src="something">                   | ![](something)
----------------------------------------+---------------------------------
<a href="...">foo</a>                   | [foo](...)
----------------------------------------+---------------------------------
<a disabled="" href="...">foo</a>       | <a disabled="" href="...">foo</a>
```

Comment: Would you be interested in a Server side **only** option? I don't know of any that are both or just browser side but I do know of one that is Server side.

Comment: @NickWilde That would be perfect. If it works on server side, it should work on client side as well. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend the [to-markdown](https://github.com/domchristie/to-markdown) on github. > An HTML to Markdown converter written in JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually I really like [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) for all my text format conversion needs. However it is Haskell based - though it does have easy install/executable options for most OSes. Of course it can't be run via JavaScript very well - Sure you can work something up with Node.js and streams; but why bother when it has already been done: [Jandoc](https://github.com/jgnewman/jandoc).

Jandoc does everything Pandoc does but with (Node.js) JavaScript wrappers.

Installation is slightly complicated;

1. Install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
2. Install the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/).
3. Run cmd prompt and execute `cabal update` (that doesn't update cabal just the package source listing, to update cabal (if desired/needed) run `cabal install cabal-install`)
4. cmd prompt: `cabal install pandoc` (It'll take a while)
5. cmd prompt: `npm install jandoc -g`

API information is in the [Jandoc Readme](https://github.com/jgnewman/jandoc#javascript-api).

To go over your requirements:

- *convert basic HTML tags to Markdown (h1...6, pre, code etc):* Yes
- *keep the HTML code if it hasn't a correspondent in Markdown (e.g. iframe):* Yes - if using the -R/--parse-raw [option](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example19/Reader-options.html). So for Jandoc via the JavaScript API you'd just include a `parseRaw: True` argument in your options list.
- *work on server side (Node.JS):* Yes
- *work on client side (browser):* **NO.** Not easily portable to browser usage either.

Comment: One could possibly use the [haste-compiler](https://github.com/valderman/haste-compiler) to convert from Haskell to ECMAScript, but I doubt that this task will be easy.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure it could be done but honestly to just support html->md it would be **much** simpler to just do it from scratch with a few regexp replacements.

Comment: Hey Nick, thank you for answer. I will review it soon, but I am busy with the baccalaureate exams.

Comment: @NickWilde If that's possible with some simple regular expressions, I would choose that way. I'm testing haskell way.